# JS regex for calculator operands and operators

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm implementing simple calculator on JS and need to validate every item in array with operands (sequence of digits) and operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `**` as a power operand).

I'm able to write regex for digits `^\d+$` and for operands `^[\+\-\*\/\]$` (have no idea how to add `**` operand), but how could I combine all the conditions in order to meet the requirement and have regex, like, "any sequence of digits OR any `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `**` operand"?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add an example of input and desired output?

Comment: I love using this site.  https://regex101.com/  Try escaping your asterisk twice.

Comment: Why regular expressions?

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to use `^` instead `**` it's pretty common...

Comment: @MartinAdámek Sure - '1', '123', '+', '-', '\*', '/', '**' should pass the check.

Comment: So you only want regex that will be able to match one of those without extra characters (no prefix/suffix)?

Comment: @Andreas It's just a requirement

Comment: @MartinAdámek Exactly, Martin, one of mentioned cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var re = /^(\d+|\*\*|[+\-*/])$/;
```

https://regexr.com/3h27d

```js
var re = /^(\d+|\*\*|[+\-*/])$/;

console.log('1'.match(re));
console.log('123'.match(re));
console.log('+'.match(re));
console.log('-'.match(re));
console.log('*'.match(re));
console.log('/'.match(re));
console.log('**'.match(re));
console.log('123+'.match(re));
console.log('2+2'.match(re));
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin, it's almost the solution for me - but seems like '123+' or '2+2' passes this regex, at the same time I need exactly 'digits_sequence' OR 'any_mentioned operand'. Please correct me in case of mistake.

Comment: Try the updated version, I forgot to remove `g` modifier I used for testing that causes this.

Comment: Seems like it's brilliant solution, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(\+|\-|\*|\/|\*\*)$
```